# jQuery - placeholder values after submiting form contact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to improve my form contact using jQuery. I want to clear input fields after clicking and show placeholders values on submit button. I have placeholders in my input fields and want to load them into variable and show them after ajax post method.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" data-error="Please write name">
```

and jQuery code:

```
form.on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var hasErrors = false;

        $('div.error_message').remove(); // Remove any old errors when submitting the form

        fields.each(function(i, elem) {
            var field = $(elem),
                empty = $.trim(field.val()) === "",
                errors = field.data("error");

            if (empty) {
                hasErrors = true;
                field.after('<div class="error_message">' + errors + '</div>'); // add new error messages
                field.toggleClass("form_error", empty);
            }
        });

        if (!hasErrors) {
             var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
             $.post(form.attr("action"), formData, function(data) {
                 console.log(data, true);

            $(".przycisk").on("click", function() {
                var placeholder = $("input[placeholder]");
                console.log(placeholder);
                $("input, textarea").val(placeholder);

            });

        } else {

        }

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to say wich attribute from input do you want to use.
in jquery is so: **.attr('attributeName')** 
now you can select your any attribute (like placeholder)

change your code like this:

```
 $("input, textarea").val(placeholder.attr('placeholder'));
```

see my code here :
https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ZyOEWX

Comment: yeah works, but cant u restore value to placeholder? I mean not value of input to field but to default properties

Comment: you want to change placeholder value? or something else?

Comment: No, i have function that shows me error when someone blur my input field, and when field is empty my data-error display under it, and when i complete form contact and click submit button i want to restore input fields to placeholders values. Not to text like in ur code but to original input with placeholders.

Comment: ok, in that case just set text of input to null.
`$(selector).val('')`
Placeholder means if input is empty, then show placeholder value

Comment: It's strange because when i set .val('') it understand me like an error, look on my code if(empty) etc.

Comment: you call form validation on blur event and set .val('') call not the event. your code should work well.
i added blur event in my code. see it again: https://codepen.io/miladfm/pen/ZyOEWX

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146441/discussion-between-miladfm-and-freestyle09).